# How pyPdf understand document boundaries?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf) I've found this code for splitting pdf page.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import copy, sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
output = PdfFileWriter()
for p in [input.getPage(i) for i in range(0,input.getNumPages())]:
    q = copy.copy(p)
    (w, h) = p.mediaBox.upperRight
    p.mediaBox.upperRight = (w/2, h)
    q.mediaBox.upperLeft = (w/2, h)
    output.addPage(p)
    output.addPage(q)
output.write(sys.stdout)
```

If one page contains four another pages like this:

```
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |
|-------+-------|
|   3   |   4   |
+-------+-------+
```

Then the code will split it to two pages (in this order) containing another two pages:

```
+-------+-------+
|   3   |   4   |
+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |
+-------+-------+
```

You can test it e.g. on [following](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/lectures/Lists4.pdf) document. If I correctly understand `upperRight`, `upperLeft` (and other) variables mentioned in code, then this is the document representation as seen by pyPdf:

```
UL(0,10)        UR(10,10)
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |
|-------+-------|
|   3   |   4   |
+-------+-------+
LL(0,0)         LR(10,0)

UL(x,y) = UpperLeft
UR(x,y) = UpperRight
LL(x,y) = LowerLeft
LR(x,y) = LowerRight
```

According to mentioned code:

```
(w, h) = p.mediaBox.upperRight
p.mediaBox.upperRight = (w/2, h)
q.mediaBox.upperLeft = (w/2, h)
```

I was expecting this output:

```
p:
+-------+
|   1   |
|-------+
|   3   |
+-------+

q:
+-------+
|   2   |
|-------+
|   4   |
+-------+
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: What did you get instead of what you expected?

Comment: It is described in post, please see figure 2. I was expecting vertical split but instead I get horizontal split in reversed order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PDF there are 2 ways to get a landscape page:

1. Define a page with width > height.
2. Define a portrait page (width < height) and a rotation (90 degrees, 270 degrees, etc).

Your sample PDF uses the second way: all the pages are 595x842 with a rotation of 270 degrees. Not taking the rotation into account causes vertical to be interpreted as horizontal and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask how can I get the degrees of page using pyPdf and if there is some general way to convert 2nd way to 1st? I've found only rotation for particular page `input.getPage(0).rotateCounterClockwise(90)` but how can I know the number of degrees to which should I rotate to?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with pyPdf. Quickly browsing the documentation didn't reveal a way to get the rotation. Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to traverse the PDF object structure. If that would be possible, it's just a matter of retrieving the page dictionaries and getting the /Rotate value.

Comment: alright got it.. 

 `pdf.getPage(1).get('/Rotate')`